# Package seems not to be well installed (file not found)

Tags: python

I am using `lazypredict` to try to find good algorithms (source: [here](https://pypi.org/project/lazypredict/)). The command `pip install` yields no error, and I have also done the upgrade of the package, yet when I use `from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyRegressor` (which should work according to the documentation) I end up with the following error:

> OSError: dlopen(/Users/gaetanlefloch/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
> Referenced from: /Users/gaetanlefloch/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
> Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file)

Did someone have the same issue (with `lazypredict` or another package), and how can I overcome it without eventually doing a manual installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the presence of a `/Users/...` path in the logs you shared, I'm assuming you are on macOS.

LightGBM requires OpenMP by default, and links to it *dynamically*. That means that it expects to find it installed on your system at runtime.

Use Homebrew ([link](https://brew.sh/)) to install OpenMP.

```bash
brew install libomp
```

If you are using `lightgbm < 4.0` and Homebrew gives you `libomp>=15.0`, you may need to help Python find that library.

You can do that modifying environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib:"${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Or by using `brew link`.

```bash
brew link --force libomp
```